# Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) usage of Chromium command lines

Tags: java, command-line, chromium-embedded

I try to set the `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` argument to JCEF but I can't find a way. The method I should be using is this one: `CefApp::onBeforeCommandLineProcessing(String, CefCommandLine).` But I can't find an example or good instructions of how to do it. `CefCommandLine` is an interface and I cannot find any implementation.

All the instructions I found are related to CEF, not JCEF and apparently there are classes that are different. Can anyone post a small example of how to pass Chromium arguments to CEF from a String `str = "--ignore-gpu-blacklist";` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several possibilities to pass over arguments from JCEF to CEF/chromium.

1) The easiest way:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    [...]

    ArrayList<String> mySwitches = new ArrayList<>();
    mySwitches.add("--persist-session-cookies=true");
    CefApp app = CefApp.getInstance(mySwitches.toArray(new String[mySwitches.size()]));
    CefClient client = app.createClient();
    CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser("http://www.google.com", false, false);

    [...]
}
```

Just create a string array, containing all your switches you want to pass over and assign that array to CefApp.getInstance(..) at the very first call of that static method.

If you have only some simple settings, you can use the class CefSettings as well and pass over the object to getInstance(). Beside that, you can combine both (there are four different "getInstance()" methods).

2) Create your own CefAppHandler implementation to do some advanced stuff.

(a) Create an own AppHandler:

```
public class MyAppHandler extends CefAppHandlerAdapter {
    public MyAppHandler(String [] args) {
        super(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeCommandLineProcessing(String process_type, CefCommandLine command_line) {
        super.onBeforeCommandLineProcessing(process_type, command_line);
        if (process_type.isEmpty()) {
            command_line.appendSwitchWithValue("persist-session-cookies","true");
        }
    }
}
```

(b) Pass AppHandler over to CefApp

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    [...]

    MyAppHandler appHandler = new MyAppHandler(args);
    CefApp.addAppHandler(appHandler);

    CefApp app = CefApp.getInstance(args);
    CefClient client = app.createClient();
    CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser("http://www.google.com", false, false);

    [...]
}
```

Using this approach you'll do two things:

(a) you pass over the program arguments (args) to CefApp and

(b) you take the advantage of having the opportunity to manipulate the complete process of parsing the arguments within onBeforeCommandLineProcessing.

If you open the example code of JCEF detailed main frame, you will find this approach implemented in:
- tests.detailed.MainFrame.MainFrame(boolean, String, String[])

So implementing the onBeforeCommandLineProcessing is equal to CEF but written in Java instead of C/C++.

Regards,
Kai

Comment: according your question: just replace "--persist-session-cookies=true" with "--ignore-gpu-blacklist" in my examples and you'll be fine. In example 2a) replace "appendSwitchWithValue(...) with appendSwitch("ignore-gpu-blacklist").

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am still getting "WebGL not supported". Am I missing something to enable WebGL?

Comment: I think WebGL is another story. Maybe the underlying shared library isn't linked/found by CEF. Did you followed https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage#Application_Layout? Try to use one of JCEF's example applications (MainFrame simple or detailed) to figure out if WebGL works with those.